# Import Javascript file into Electron loadURL

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I was wondering how could I import a javascript file into a website with Electron?
By that I mean:

```js
mainWindow.loadURL("https://a.website");
mainWindow.loadScript("./script.js");
```

Load script does not exist, and I want to add script.js so that it is part of the webpage displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can import your js files in the main html file using the script tag and pointing to the folder that contains your js file.

```
<script src="./assets/js/tfjs-core.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        preload:`${__dirname}/script.js`
      }
  })

  win.loadURL('https://google.com')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow() 
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```